# Spilled Pepsi on my laptop

Tags: windows

Now it's all messed up. It's typing on its own, the keys won't press down, and whenever I type something it just spouts out "ZXCS."

What do I do, and how do I disable the laptop keyboard in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

If you pry on a key with e.g. two table-knifes, from opposite sides (straight up, no tilting!), it should come off.
By this you should be able to pry off all of them.

Now all the rest is cleaning it up; which might be a very tedious task.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard is a field replaceable unit (FRU), you should buy a new one and replace the keyboard. If it is a FRU, you can remove the keyboard, but I'm not sure this will allow you to continue to boot the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. I removed the keyboard. *(Search for some youtube videos about how to remove keyboard from your particular laptop model)*.

After that, I tried cleaning it with Isopropyl Rubbing Alcohol *(got that from pharmacy)*, but it didn't do much effect.

Finally, I simply rinsed the keyboard under running water. I kept pressing stuck keys, until all of them were acting normally under water. Then I left it to dry for couple of days.

Since then it is working fine.